# Renew expired Recurly accounts

Tags: recurly

Recurly API theme. I need to find decision for renew expired accounts. As i know these accounts can't be renewed. So i see one way: create new subscription with the same parameters (plan_code, quantity etc) as was before.
My question: Can i create new subscription for existing Recurly account code without having to ask the user his billing info again?

It would be good have class function like:

```
duplicateSubscription(from_account_code, existing_subscription_id)
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes - so long as the account has not been closed (which deletes billing information), the billing information is stored on the account. You can add a new subscription to the account by referencing the account code, and the billing information on file will be used for purchasing.